# ASP.NET MVC Populating DropDownListFor based on DB call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am building a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 site, using Entity Framework to build the model based on some tables in an already existing Oracle database (in other words, I used the 'database first' methodology to have my model built). I now have a simple blog type site, which I am quite familiar with as I have been learning MVC in a number of languages.

I want to change some of the auto-generated views. One piece I would like to change in particular is that I have a field in one of my tables called 'Visible'. This is simply a numeric value (0 or 1) indicating whether or not a display application should use the row as display data. Currently, I have the simple text field that is auto-generated:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VISIBLE)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VISIBLE)
</div>
```

What I would like to do is replace this with a drop down box with string values like True and False. The application should display any entry with a 0 as false and vice versa. If a user wants to flip the toggle, the drop down should allow them to do that and understand to make the numeric update when clicking submit. How can this be done?

I have seen countless examples where the drop-down was going to be filled with more then just two values, and in those cases I understand that you can add logic to your controller that pulls all the distinct values, puts them in a list, then adds the list to the ViewBag. However, in my case with only two possible numeric values, it seems like there should be a simpler, more accepted way to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Following Quinton's answer, I am trying to place said code in my model. Here is my current model:

```
    namespace CurrentActivityBlog
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

        public partial class TBLCURRENTACTIVITY
        {
            public string TITLE { get; set; }
            public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime DATETIME { get; set; }
            public short VISIBLE { get; set; }
            public decimal ID { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<SelectedListItem> PossibleValues { get; set; }

        public TBLCURRENTACTIVITY() {
          PossibleValues = new[] { new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Hidden"       },              
              new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Visible" } }; 
        }

        }
    }
```

I am unable to build this solution, but Visual Studio 2010 is telling me that

*"the type or namespace name 'SelectedListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

As you can see, I have

using System.Web.UI.controls

and have added the reference to System.Web. Is there anything I am forgetting, or anything I should know about (such as models generated using EF behaving differently then one might expect, etc.)?

Thanks again.

Comment: SelectListItem is part of System.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 1):

The one line solution to it would be:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.VISIBLE.ToString(), new [] {new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Hidden"}, new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Visible"}})
```

but you probably don't want domain logic in your view.  So add the possible items to your Model (or from the controller):

```
    public class MyModel {
        public int VISIBLE { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PossibleValues { get; set; }

        public MyModel() {
            PossibleValues = new[] { new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Hidden" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Visible" } }; 
        }
    }
```

and then your razor code:

```
    @Html.DropDownList(Model.VISIBLE.ToString(), Model.PossibleValues)
```

Obviously "Hidden" and "Visible" descriptions can be replaced with "False" and "True" or whatever.

You could also create and `Editor and Display Template` for that specific field.  Checkout ScottGu's blog post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx), search for "UI Helper Templating Support" and you'll see how to create a editor template and how to render a specific template by name.

**EDIT:**

If your model is not part of your MVC project, then referencing any classes that are in the MVC assemblies would require a explicit add reference.  You can avoid this though by initializing any MVC assembly types in your model from your controller, like such:

```
    public class MyModel {
            public int VISIBLE { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PossibleValues { get; set; }
    }
```

controller action method:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int Id) {
        ...
        myModelInstance. PossibleValues = new[] { new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Hidden" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Visible" } }; 
        ...
        Return View(myModel);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Quinton. I believe that both the second or third will suit my purposes. I am having a slight issue in trying it out though. Could you take a look at my update and let me know if anything stands out as wrong?

Comment: Cool, you can avoid an explicit MVC assembly reference from your project that contains your model - see my edit.